# MAX1771 MAXIM 4.2V TO 5V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, 5v

I am working with MAX1771 Step Up converter, from Maxim in the adjustable mode. I would like to have a continous output voltage of 5V so I have used the application circuit that you can find in the datasheet: http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1771.pdf (page 13, Figure 5).

But I have some problems with the output because it is not continous and it has a lot of peaks (I attach a capture from the oscilloscope).

Can someone help me with this issue?

[image: Output signal 5V]

**update:**

When Iconnect a load (in this case, 2 diodes LED in series) the output have the following form:[image: 2DiodesLED]

The leds are working with 20mA.

**update:**

First at all, thank you for the answers.

I have attached now the capture, sorry for the inconvenences.

I hope it will help you with the possible solutions.

Comment: Switch mode converters are sensitive to layout. Please add a photograph of the circuit you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

For your application diagram 2C in the data sheet with the feedback resistors changed to give 5V output would be better. Figure 5 is for where the input voltage can either be lower or higher than the output voltage.  If you wish to get 5V from l LiIon cell then the input voltage will never be higher than 4.2V so the simpler circuit will work better.

We don't see the oscilloscope capture so we cannot comment on the problem you are having.

You do need to use good decoupling on the input and output (e.g C4 on fig 2c).  Normal aluminium electrolytics often have too high a series resistance to work well.  Tantalums or ceramics are good.

You also need very good low impedance grounding or you will get voltages across the ground inductance and resistance - a plug-in breadboard will probably not work acceptably.

It looks like the ESR of the output capacitor is too high.  What type of capacitor is it? What is its ESR?

As I mentioned above you need a low ESR type - ceramic, tantalum or aluminum polymer.  A normal aluminum electrolytic is often not good enough.

When Q1 is turned off the current from L1 is transferred into the output capacitor - any ESR will cause a voltage spike.  The gradual decline for each cycle is the ripple, you can reduce that by increasing the output capacitor.

Comment: I am using a Tamtalum capacitor of 470uF in the output and the same for the input. So, I dont think that the problem if about the ESR.
Do you have another suggestion? 

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The other thing to be very careful about is where the scope ground clip is placed - what you are seeing may not really be there.  One test is to leave the ground clip in place and touch the scope tip to the ground clip - there should be nothing on the scope but often you can see a significant amount of noise.  I found the best way to avoid this problem is to hardwire some thin coax to the point you are measuring.  You should be able to measure down to sub-millivolt levels.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the datasheet, output ripple is caused by filter capacitors with too much ESR. Switch to a capacitor with lower ESR.

Comment: As you can see in the comment above, this problem cant exist, because Im using tamtalum capacitors